# Integrated files disappear from a pending changelist at p4v

Tags: perforce

Our user performed an integration between branches. 
Integrated files were placed in a pending changelist but they are invisible when I look 
at this changelist in p4v. 
I can see them when I look on this changelist when I connected to another workspace, I can also see then in Eclipse. 
When I choose to Resolve conflicts on this changelist it works too, but 
when I try to submit the changes, there is nothing there.
After I installed a new version of p4v, the problematic pending 
changelist appeared with a question mark (red triangle with a question 
mark).
Any Ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried emailing Perforce support with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer from Perforce support:

This may be a working and locks out of sync
issue.  Can you run the following server command:

*p4d -r $P4ROOT -xf 925*

Where "$P4ROOT" is the location of the db.* files.

Answer (score 0):

P4V.exe allows the user to specify a filter on his workspace.  Perhaps the workspace had a filter applied, such that the GUI did not show the files, where the command line client and others (ie Eclipse) would not be privy to this filter and would show the files.

Another possibility is that the user was logged in under a workspace other than his default, and the files were checked out in his default workspace.  It would be easy to then find these files in his default by looking at pending changelists for all users.